# Programmatically remove the left side image of button but not on right side?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-fragments

Hello i have button with two images drawable left and right,i want to remove only left side image,and want to keep the right side image my button xml code is below.

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/fragment_add_to_cart_btn_proceed_to_checkout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorRed"
    android:drawableEnd="@drawable/ic_action_next"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_rounded_cart"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:text="@string/proceed_to_checkout"
    android:textColor="@color/colorWhite" />
```

i have applied some code like below but its not working

`button.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);`

if you have any solution please reply?
thank you.

Comment: Simply remove this line: `android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_rounded_cart"`

Comment: I want to do this programmatically.

Comment: Then use `button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, your_right_drawable, null);` Reference: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do like this inside `onCreate`. Give `image` resource for which you need to show else will be given `0`.

```
int imgResource = R.drawable.common_google_signin_btn_icon_dark;
fragment_add_to_cart_btn_proceed_to_checkout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fragment_add_to_cart_btn_proceed_to_checkout);
fragment_add_to_cart_btn_proceed_to_checkout.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, imgResource, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, <your_left_drawable>, 0);
```

Hope it will help you out.

Answer (score 1):

You should use `button.setCompoundDrawables(null, null, R.drawable.ic_action_next, null);`

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, <The right drawable>, 0);
```

Order:

```
setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds (int left, int top, int right, int bottom)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.ic_rounded_cart, 0); // if you want to remove the left drawable
```